# Return a merged object composed by two different Observables with dependencies with RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm going to explain the context I have before explain the problem design a service with Angular and RxJS.

I have one object with this model:

```
{
  id: string;
  title: string;
  items: number[];
}
```

I obtain each object of this type (called "element") through `GET /element/:id`

Each element has an `items: number[]` that contains an array of numbers and each number has an URL so I do a new `GET /element/:id/:itemNumber` for each number and return the items detail. That item detail model is like:

```
{
  idItem: string;
  title: string;
}
```

So in my service I want to serve to the components a method that it will return an Observable, it will obtain an array of objects, where each object has the element model with one addition property that will be an array of its detailed items. So, I'm going to show what I have:

The service:

```
getElement(id: string): any {
  return this.http.get<Element>(this.basePath + `/element/${id}`).pipe(
    map(element => this.getAllItemsDetail(element))
}

getAllItemsDetail(element: Element): any {
  return of(...element.items).pipe(
    map(val => this.getItemDetail(element.id, val)),
    concatAll()
  );
}
```

My problem is, I'm not understanding how I can, in RxJS, after the `map(element => this.getAllItemsDetail(element))` in the `getElement` method, merge the items array returned by it and the previous element I have before the map that has the element object. I need to add "anything" after that map to compute an Object.Assign to merge the both objects.

**EDIT**

With the answer of @chiril.sarajiu, he gives me more than one clue, with `switchMap` I can map the observable (`map` is used for objects, "do a compute  with the result object"). So my code, it's not the most pretty version I know..., I will try on it, but it works. So the final code looks like this:

```
getElement(id: string): any {
  return this.http.get<Element>(this.basePath + `/element/${id}`).pipe(
    switchMap(element => this.getAllItemsDetail(element)),
    map(result => { return Object.assign({}, result.element, {itemsDetail: result.items})})
  );
}

getAllItemsDetail(element: Element): any {
  const results$ = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < element.items.length; i++) {
    results$.push(this.getItemDetail(element.id, element.items[i]));
  }

  return zip(...results$).pipe(
    map(items => { return Object.assign({}, { element, items })})
  );
}
```

Be aware of the possibility about zip will not emit values if the results$ is empty, in that case you can add of(undefined) to the results$ array and after take into account that items will be `[undefined]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map another observable you should use `switchMap` function instead of `map`
So

```
getElement(id: string): any {
  return this.http.get<Element>(this.basePath + `/element/${id}`).pipe(
    switchMap(element => this.getAllItemsDetail(element))
}
```

**UPDATE**

Consider this [medium article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)

Comment: Ok but, what is the difference? After the switchMap how can I use in the pipe the element returned in first place (element) and the objects returned by getAllItemsDetail?? This is my problem, I need both in that method to do a merge and return it, I think with of... are you understand me?

Comment: Mmmm mergeMap, the example in the article give me I clue, I'm going to test it

Comment: I'll provide an example on stackblitzz in a bit.

Comment: Thanks man! I got it, don't worry, I used switchMap as you did, and in the getAll... method I mapped both objects, and the switchMap of course have both, don't waste your time because you have helped a lot and I have it ;D

Comment: Glad to help! Would love to see the implementation, if it's on github by any chance :D

Comment: Of course, I will add to the question when I will prettify ;D

Comment: It's not the most pretty code, but for the purpose of the question it's perfect. Now I have time to waste improving my knowledge about rxjs and doing a best code, thanks again man!

Comment: nice, just one thing though, in here `{element: element, items: items}` you can omit the second items, it will work w/o them `{ element, items }`